# Is there any way to find what are the methods invoked in a Java Class/Java Method programmatically by using Eclipse JDT?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to find the the method to method call in Java by using eclipse JDT. I want a list of all methods that a method calls in Java.

Comment: You use the information provided by the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) to do that.

Comment: Yes, but I want to cover all the cases such as anonymous classes.

Comment: All the information about everything is in the AST.